# GeoServer: Creating CQL-filter which only filters dates for given weekday

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I use a GeoServer which i query over Openlayers with WMS and CQL.

I have a date field in my database which i want to filter with
CQL.

I want only have Dates which has the weekday monday.

The Result would contain only two dates.

```
id   time   
1    12.10.2015 12:26:31
2    19.10.2015 13:45:00
3    20.10.2015 12:16:11
4    21.10.2015 12:03:45
5    22.10.2015 12:01:45
```

I don't see any way to do that. Are the some functions to do that?
I was thinking of use a formular to calculate the weekday, but therefore i need the day, month, year and century from a date and i don't see any way to extracts this values.

Comment: If it is your own GeoServer and database you can probably create a weekday column making a new layer through SQL View http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html and by selecting weekday from date with SQL http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/0898jbyc4z/weekday-from-timestamp.

Comment: This will work. Never thought about such a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not make an answer of this so i could mark the question as solved?

Comment: Or you could write a custom filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is your own GeoServer and database you can create a weekday attribute by making a new layer through SQL View http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Select the weekday from from the date column with SQL

```
select to_char(DATE '2001-02-16','Day')
Friday
```

http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/0898jbyc4z/…;. – user30184 6 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

GeoTools (and hence GeoServer) allows you to write your own custom functions to use in filters. There is a [tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html) that explains all the steps. So all you would need is a function implementation that returned the day of the week, something like:

```
package spike;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize.NA;

import org.geotools.filter.capability.FunctionNameImpl;
import org.geotools.util.Converters;
import org.opengis.filter.capability.FunctionName;
import org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression;
import org.opengis.filter.expression.ExpressionVisitor;
import org.opengis.filter.expression.Function;
import org.opengis.filter.expression.Literal;

public class DayOfWeekFunction implements Function {

    static FunctionName NAME = new FunctionNameImpl("DayOfWeek", String.class,
        FunctionNameImpl.parameter("date", Date.class));
    private List<Expression> params;
    private Literal fallback;

    public DayOfWeekFunction(List<Expression> params, Literal fallback) {
        if (params == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("No parameters supplied");
        }
        if (params.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("DayOfWeek(date) requires exactly one argument");
        }
        this.params = params;
        this.fallback = fallback;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(Object object) {
        return evaluate(object, String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(Object object, Class<T> context) {
        Expression dateExpression = params.get(0);
        Date date = dateExpression.evaluate(object, Date.class);
        String day = new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(date);
        return Converters.convert(day, context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor, Object extraData) {
        return visitor.visit(this, extraData);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public FunctionName getFunctionName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Expression> getParameters() {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Literal getFallbackValue() {

        return fallback;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution when i would have a complex feature. The only question is where do you integrate this in my geoserver?

Comment: You build a jar with the filter and the META-INF/service/... file in it and then drop it into your geoserver WEB-INF/lib folder and restart. The rest is magic!